# Как перестать выполнять приложение если получен exit status 0?

Tags: bash

Пытаюсь выполнить в бесконечном цикле приложение, до тех пор пока оно не выдаст exit status 0. Но ничего не выходит. Что я делаю не так?

```
#!/bin/bash
retVal=$?
for ((;;))
do
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
    youtube-dl https://youtu.be/H90GFYTpFqE
else
break
fi
done
exit $retVal
```

Comment: можно предположить, что вы хотели строку `retVal=$?` поместить не второй, а седьмой (сразу после вызова скрипта `youtube-dl`), а второй строкой поместить `retVal=0`. но почему-то не поместили ни ту ни другую.

Comment: тогда он никогда не зайдет в if и не выполнит команду `youtube-dl`

Comment: да, прошу прощения, действительно опечатался: `retVal=1`.

Comment: спасибо Вам большое :)

Comment: Да просто к команде прописать `&& break` да и всё, чё мудрить-то с переменными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я запарился  Спасибо за помощь @aleksandr-barakin

Теперь всё работает.

```
#!/bin/bash
retVal=1
for ((;;))
do
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
  youtube-dl https://youtu.be/H90GFYTpFqE
  retVal=$?
else
  echo "All downloaded "
  break
fi
done
exit $retVal
```

Ну или так можно. Спасибо за наводку @andreymal

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((;;))
do
  youtube-dl https://youtu.be/H90GFYTpFqE && break
done
```